# pass parameters with post directly in the url without using forms

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to pass parameters via post directly in the url, without using forms nor input buttons.
Not long ago I implemented a working solution, but now I'm reviewing my own the scripts and I can't have them do what I want. I don't remember having to tweak settings when the solution was working.
I give you a very simple example

```
<form method="post">
<name="x" />
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

If I call the script from the browser with

```
http://x.x.x.x/test.php?x=a
```

I can see that my parameter has not been passed.

```
Array ( )
```

I suspected a different behavior between php 5 and 7 but I tested both, also different browsers and 2 distros (linux and aws ami1).
Any hint? I still have the old scripts and they're all in this format, also I remember calling the url and the parameters in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Any (properly encoded) data in the query string of the URL will be placed in `$_GET` by PHP.

`$_POST` will *only* contain properly encoded `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` data from the request body.

The only way to get any other kind of data into `$_POST` is to write it there with custom PHP code (and I can't think of any reason to do that other than for a quick and dirty backwards compatibility hack with pre-existing code that expects it in `$_POST` in a system that has changed the way it collects data).

(For "quick and dirty hack" read "you need to refactor this properly")

---

Asides:

- There is no `<name>` element in HTML
- Form data will only get to the request body if you put it there by submitting the form (or by copying it to a request made with Ajax).

Answer (score -1):

I found out that I was actually NOT passing values in the url, they were in the body.
I don't get why Quentin says that "There is no  element in HTML" the script works fine, it was a mistake on the client I was using.